# Left join in Linq giving wrong output?

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have two lists with common registration number in both lists and I need only Id property from the first list and two properties from the second list but I am getting 5 records as output but i need only 3 records as mentioned in output below. You can find the following code:

```
List<A> lstA = new List<A>();
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 1, Name = "A", Reg = 3 });
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 2, Name = "B", Reg = 4 });
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 3, Name = "C", Reg = 5 });

List<A> lstB = new List<A>();
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 4, Name = "D", Reg = 3 });
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 5, Name = "E", Reg = 3 });
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 6, Name = "F", Reg = 5 });

var query = from a in lstA
            join b in lstB on a.Reg equals b.Reg
            select new { a.Id, b.Name, b.Reg };
var output = query.ToList();
```

But I need the following output:

```
ID Name Reg
1   D    3
1   E    3
3   F    5
```

But it's returning following:

```
ID Name Reg
4   A    3
5   A    3
4   A    5
5   A    5
6   AB   5
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The code in your question runs & gives desired output. So does the query in the answer when the input data is updated to agree with yor question. Your problem is not in the code you give. Your question should not be reopened. This is why you are required to give a [mcve] for a code question--*complete* cut & paste & runnable code. PS When you are the poster use one @x per comment to notify one commenter x among others. Google 'stackexchange notification'.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding all objects to `lstA`. Add objects to `lstB` to get desired results.

For given result, you don't need `Left Join` and neither your code has that.

```
List<A> lstA = new List<A>();
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 1, Name = "A", Reg = 3 });
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 2, Name = "B", Reg = 4 });
lstA.Add(new A { Id = 3, Name = "C", Reg = 5 });

List<A> lstB = new List<A>();
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 4, Name = "D", Reg = 3 });
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 5, Name = "E", Reg = 4 });
lstB.Add(new A { Id = 6, Name = "F", Reg = 5 });

var output = (from a in lstA
              join b in lstB on a.Reg equals b.Reg
              select new { a.Id, b.Name, b.Reg }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your desired output is coming from the edited code. Be careful while posting the code on forum.

Comment: No it's returning ID Name Reg
       ID Name Reg
    4   A    3
    5   A    3
    4   A    5
    5   A    5
    6   AB   5

Comment: Kindly check my edited question. It's not giving the required output by your mentioned answer. Please suggest how can i do it?